# when I try to subtract I get an error in response

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

this is a piece of code. When I want to take away from the available data in my SQLite, I get an error in response. Let's say the initial data is 0, I subtract 100, after that, when I try to subtract more, it subtracts, and then writes an error

```
cursor.execute("SELECT usd FROM balans")
FOR_USD = int(str(cursor.fetchone()).replace(',', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', ''))

def checkcmbo():
    FOR_USD = int(FOR_USD) - int(num.get())
    FOR_USD = f"""Update balans set usd = {FOR_USD}"""
    cursor.execute(FOR_USD)
    connect.commit()
```

After running I get this error in the console

```
File "C:\pyt\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
File "C:/Users/d6692/PycharmProjects/ahmed/ahmed.py", line 91, in checkcmbo
        FOR_USD = int(FOR_USD) - int(num.get())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Update balans set usd = -850'
```

Comment: You should find out how to use tuples properly.

Comment: Also post more code. I need to see what `num` is

Comment: If only `checkcmbo()` is executed, I got  `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'FOR_USD' referenced before assignment` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Currently after you execute `chekcmbo` once, the value of `FOR_USD` is your SQL statement, `Update balans set usd = -850`. Therefore when you run it again you try to cast the SQL statement to an integer, which causes the error. This can be fixed simply by replacing the variable name for the SQL string, for example:

```
FOR_USD = cursor.fetchone()[0] #This is a much better way to get the value than .replace()

def checkcmbo():
    FOR_USD = int(FOR_USD) - int(num.get())
    FOR_USD_SQL = "UPDATE balans SET usd = ?"
    cursor.execute(FOR_USD_SQL, (FOR_USD,))
```

This way the `FOR_USD` integer does not get overwritten by the SQL statement.
**Edit**
Thanks Cool Cloud for pointing out the original answer was vulnerable to injection.

Comment: @CoolCloud That is true, I'll edit my answer